# Going one directory behind using OS in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, operating-system

I have a file sample.py in bin folder. Path of bin - /username/packagename/bin

so when i am doing, dir = os.getcwd(), it gives me the path of the bin(mentioned above).

So, is there a way that i can go one directory behind, that is /username/packagename ??

Comment: `>>> up_one_dir = os.chdir('..')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If what you want is to get the path of directory, one directory behind current working directory, you can use `os.path.join()` with relative paths and then convert them to absolute path (if necessary) using `os.path.abspath`. Example -

```
one_dir_up_path = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.getcwd(),'..'))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
os.path.dirname('/username/packagename/bin')

# Result: /username/packagename #
```